# Doubt about Reynolds number formula

Tags: fluid-mechanics, building-physics

In fluid dynamics, when I have to compute Reynolds number, I was taught to differentiate between two cases: $$ 1)\space \frac{\rho\cdot v\cdot d}{\mu}$$ or $$2)\space \frac{v\cdot d}{\mu}$$

but, why do I have to do this? Why shouldn't I simply use the first formula? what is the criteria to use in order to include or omit the density (i.e $\rho$)?

Comment: Is diameter always the characteristic length? what happens if the duct is rectangular?

Comment: @SolarMike It doesn't matter, diameter can be circular or rectangular, I guess

Comment: Have you checked out any books like Mechanics of Fluids by Massey?

Comment: yes, but it uses only the first formula, it always includes density

Comment: when I solve exercises, sometimes it's true and sometimes I get an absurd number (i.e too small or huge)

Comment: Are you sure the symbol in the denominator in the second case is $\mu$ and not $\nu$?

Comment: Perhaps you should read this: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/dynamic-absolute-kinematic-viscosity-d_412.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen the second formula.
It's incorrect, unless it's a specific application like water where density is numerically 1 g/cc and they just don't write it.

The first formula

$$\mathrm{Re} =\frac{\rho vd}{\mu}$$

is the definition of Reynolds number and is always true. But you may sometimes see it written in terms of kinematic viscosity $\nu$ which is equal to $\mu/\rho$, and so you will see:

$$\mathrm{Re} =\frac{vd}{\nu}$$

In other more specialized geometries like a porous bed or perforated plate, you may see the Reynolds number defined in terms of other parameters like the mass flow rate and some dimension.  But for flow in a pipe, the first formula is always true.